# Which text file encoding should i use to be compatible between Windows and Linux?

Tags: encoding, unicode, subtitles, utf-8

If i want text file (in this case .srt subtitle file) or just plain text file with various characters including ěščřžýáíéůú (WINDOWS-1250) in general to be working well both on Windows and Linux, which encoding should i use?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend UTF-8 and using notepad++ on Windows to change the encoding if needed. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What apparently worked to fix Windows file displaying incorrectly on Linux was Linux command `recode ms-ee "filename"`.

Then the Linux text editors and media player VLC(set to read subtitles as UTF-8 and 1252) can read the file properly. Then i copied file and tried it on Windows 7 and also opened OK in Notepad, Notepad++ and in Windows media player subtitles OK. What are your thoughts on this and on that recode command? Is it safe and best compatibility for various character sets?

Comment: Linux, MacOS and Windows use different character combinations for end-of-line, for example: https://confluence.qps.nl/fledermaus7/questions-answers/other/differences-in-end-of-line-characters-mac-windows-and-linux . Therefore, files must be converted, as you did with *recode*. Some applications, e.g., *Notepad++*, can adapt to different encoding schemes or transform files to other schemes. Then there EBCDIC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC